# Gulp-Ruby-SASS erroring even though CSS file is empty

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm currently trying to update our boilerplate for web apps and its build tools.

I'm getting this error currently:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Broken @import declaration of "branding", Broken @import declaration of "helper", Broken @import declaration of "routing"
```

I'm assuming it is some kind of caching problem because the .scss file it's supposed to parse is empty. The project with files like `branding` and `routing` is a different one and I'm definitely not in the wrong folder in the terminal.

How could I fix this? Can I / Should I clear the cache? How?

For completion:
Gulpfile Styles Task:

```
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('src/css/app.scss', { 
      sourcemap: true,
      noCache: true
  })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Download as ZIP, **don't clone this repo** if you want to create a new project. Only clone if you want to update/change the boilerplate.",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.12",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "main-bower-files": "git://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://codeofsumit:091210sk@github.com/codeofsumit/boilerplate.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/codeofsumit/boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/codeofsumit/boilerplate"
}
```

Comment: I checked out your project at https://github.com/codeofsumit/boilerplate/tree/sourcemaps and it compiled perfectly fine. So if it's really a cache problem, try killing the `.sass-cache` directory (it's hidden on some OSs) and run it again. Another way of testing would be a clean checkout in a new folder with a new `npm install`

Comment: @ddprrt do you have any idea where the `.sass-cache` folder is located? I'm on OSX and haven't changed any default setting.

Comment: Usually in your project folder, where you call your Gulpfile. Open the terminal and type `ls -la` there, that should show you all contents

Comment: it's not in there :(

Comment: have you tried a clean checkout from your source repo? Does the same error occur then?

Comment: I've run into this same problem with a very similar gulp task. I got rid of `.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' })).pipe(minifyCss()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))` and it started to work. Added the minification back and it instantly broke again. Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @VartanSimonian no not yet :(